# A boundedness question.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a mapping that sends each real number $\lambda$ to a positive real number $b_{\lambda}$. Show the following set is not bounded.
$B=\{ b_{\lambda_1}+b_{\lambda_2}....+b_{\lambda_k} \mid k \in \Bbb N,  \lambda_k \in R \text{ are  distinct}\} $. Consider the case that $\lambda$s were integers instead of real numbers as well.

Well, I wasn't able to start solving this one because although each term of each sum might be bounded, there is no need for its sum to be bounded.

Comment: In which set are the $\lambda$ supposed to belong?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. Lambdas are real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: have a look for the cardinalities of the sets
$$\{ \lambda \in \mathbb R \;|\; b_\lambda \in (1/(n+1), 1/n]\}$$
for $n \in \mathbb N$
and of
$$\{ \lambda \in \mathbb R \;|\; b_\lambda > 1\}$$

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis,

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
b : & \mathbb R & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & \lambda & \longmapsto & b_\lambda \end{array}$$ is supposed to be a one-to-one map. Without loss of generality by changing $b$ into $-b$, we can suppose that $b(\mathbb R) \cap (0,\infty)$ is uncountable. Therefore, one of the sets $B_n = b(\mathbb R) \cap (1/n, \infty)$ is uncountable  (a union of countably many countable sets is countable). Taking $k$ distinct elements of $B_n$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^k b_{\lambda_i} \ge k/n$ proving that $B$ in unbounded.

The result doesn't hold if the $\lambda$s belong to $\mathbb N$. Take for example $b_n = 1/n^2$. As $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, every partial sum is also finite.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Without you, i could not come up with the approach using partial sums of series. This was very insightful.

Comment: I don't think the hypothesis implies injectivity of $\lambda \to b_{\lambda}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Reading again the question, I think that you're right. The answer can be adapted to separate the cases where $b(\mathbb R)$ is countable vs . uncountable.